# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT "region", sum("items"), sum("actcost")
FROM "apr","Regions"
WHERE "bnfname" LIKE 'Flucloxacillin %' AND apr.sha=Regions.sha
GROUP BY "region"
```

Following error given:

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "regions"

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I believe its a completely query. I am trying to use a key (in this case SHA) to get sum of items and act cost per region.
I am new to sql so my question might be completely foolish

Comment: It is a complete query, but you should stop using those old and ancient implicit joins. Use an explicit `JOIN` instead. And you should really avoid quoted identifiers, they are much more trouble than they are worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT "region", sum("items"), sum("actcost")
FROM "apr","Regions"
WHERE "bnfname" LIKE 'Flucloxacillin %' AND "apr"."sha"="Regions"."sha"
GROUP BY "region"
```

Comment: I tried it earlier. When I do as you said it gives me the following error:
ERROR: relation "regions" does not exist

Comment: Try to change your where-statement so that it becomes: WHERE "bnfname" LIKE 'Flucloxacillin %' AND "apr".sha="Regions".sha

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT apr.region, 
       SUM(apr.items), 
       SUM(apr.actcost) 
FROM   apr, 
       Regions 
WHERE  apr.bnfname LIKE 'Flucloxacillin %' 
       AND apr.sha = regions.sha 
GROUP  BY apr.region
```

Or use join

```
SELECT apr.region, 
       SUM(apr.items), 
       SUM(apr.actcost) 
FROM   apr 
       join regions 
         ON apr.sha = regions.sha 
WHERE  apr.bnfname LIKE 'Flucloxacillin %' 
GROUP  BY apr.region
```

Comment: region column is actually in the Regions table. I tried your advice with correct tables but it still didn't work.

Comment: You should create sql fiddle now

Comment: SELECT Regions.region, 
       SUM(apr.items), 
       SUM(apr.actcost) 
FROM   apr 
       join "Regions" 
         ON apr.sha = Regions.sha 
WHERE  apr.bnfname LIKE 'Flucloxacillin %' 
GROUP  BY Regions.region 

Just tried doing the following, I get the FROM clause error again

Comment: Table name is `Regions` or `regions`

Comment: Thank you for your help Shubham, I finally managed to solve it using Skywalker's approach.